# ¿Como puedo obtener el valor de un campo de base de datos por medio de un modelo en Django?

Tags: python, django

Buenas tardes amigos de stackoverflow.

Tengo la siguiente duda como puedo obtener el valor de un campo por medio de una query en un modelo de una base de datos por favor.

Aqui esta el codigo.

Views.py

```
class UserFormView(View):
form_class = UserForm
template_name = "registration/registration_form.html"

def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

#process form data
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        #cleaned (normalized) data
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        #Quiero obtener el password segun el username
        user_password = User.objects.get(username=username)
        validate_email(username, user_password, email)
        #returns User objects if credentials are correct
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth_login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Models.py

```
    from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save



class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False, blank=False)
    password_token = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Sencillo: no uses django. Usa python

Answer (score 0):

deberias pedir el campo password al usuario q estas obteniendo en user_password o sea:

```
validate_email(username, user_password.password, email)
```

*objeto.campo*

saludos

Comment: Hola, me da error si supieras a la hora de validar !

Comment: Exactamente q quieres validar? 
la funcion q estas usando antes validate_email q se supone q hace?

Comment: Que campo exactamente ?